# Swiss Currency by using culture code

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, currency

I have a small problem. I´m using culture-codes to put the value into the correct format.

used culture code: de_CH
I was hoping to get this format:    CHF 18.99 
But I got that:                     Fr. 18.99

I used this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5

Somebody with an idea out there?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really strange but you are right.

If you retrieving the language_country(DE_CH) from a DE or a list, you may write something like that to replace it:

```
SET @currency = FormatCurrency(1234.567,@language_country)

IF @language_country == "de_CH" OR @language_country == "fr_CH" THEN
SET @currency = Replace(@currency,'fr.','CHF')
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's currency, and language doesn't matter, you could remove the language portion of the culture code and pass just the 'CH' value.

That might look like this:

```
SET @locale = [locale from audience]
SET @localeRows = BuildRowSetFromString(@local, '_')

/* if @locale is format [language]_[country], set currency locale to the 3rd element of the rowset, else set it to the @locale value */
SET @currencyLocale = IIF(rowCount(@localeRows) == 3, Field(Row(@localRows,3),1), @locale)
SET @orderTotal = FormatCurrency(@orderTotal,@currencyLocale,2,)
```

Also, this is probably the most accurate depiction of which locales formatCurrency() will support:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx

And, honestly, you can just override the currency symbol if you'd like using the fourth parameter of formatCurrency, if it's returning something you don't want:

```
SET @orderTotal = FormatCurrency(@orderTotal,@locale,2,IIF(@locale == 'DE_CH', 'CHF', ))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sam: I tried your last idea but it doesn't work. I guess I made a mistake by using your term in my function.

My working function (except the CH case) before:

```
set @dynamicprice = Concat("%", "%=FormatCurrency('",@Product1_price,"','",@culturecode,"')=%", "%")
```

function afterwards:

```
set @dynamicprice = Concat("%", "%=FormatCurrency('",@Product1_price,"','",@culturecode,"'IIF(@culturecode == 'de_CH', 'CHF', ))=%", "%")
```

I am getting that error message:
[image]

Comment: The error message looks like there is a missing comma in front of IIF